# Erro envio JSON por Socket

Tags: java

Quando a String do JSON é muito grande, há perda de parte da String no envio. Estou enviando assim:

```
private void btComunicarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        List<PessoaMOD> pessoas = new ArrayList<PessoaMOD>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 2000; i++) {
            pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(i, "Pessoa " + i));
        }

        try {
            Socket cliente = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 12345);
            enviarMensagem(codificarListarDiretorio(pessoas), cliente);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
        }
    }  

public ByteArrayOutputStream codificarListarDiretorio(List<PessoaMOD> pessoas) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        dos.write(gson.toJson(pessoas).getBytes());
        return bos;
    }

public void enviarMensagem(ByteArrayOutputStream mensagem, Socket socket) throws IOException {
        byte[] msg = mensagem.toByteArray();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeInt(msg.length); //O tamanho da mensagem
        out.write(msg); //Os dados
        out.flush();
    }
```

e recebo no servidor assim:

```
int tamanhoMsg = entrada.readInt();                   
byte[] bufferJson = new byte[tamanhoMsg];
entrada.read(bufferJson, 0, bufferJson.length);
String json = new String(bufferJson);
```

Só que a String do Json não chega completa quando é muito grande.

O que acontece é que o numero de bytes é maior do que o **lenght** suporta, então o tamanho da mensagem não envia completo.

Também tentei enviar pelo método **writeUTF()**;

Mas como a String é grande, gera esse erro: **encoded string too long: 677789 bytes**

Comment: como é instanciado out ?

Comment: não é "out", é "dos", tinha colocado errado. Você teria uma luz pra me dar neste problema? rsrs

Answer (score 1):

Tenta mudar a parte da leitura do JSON no seu código no servidor de `DataInputStream` para `BufferedReader`:

```
// ...
long tamanhoMsg = entrada.readLong();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
            // guava library - limita a leitura de um input stream
            ByteStreams.limit(        
                inputStream,                // input stream do socket
                tamanhoMsg                  // tamanho máximo a ser lido do input stream
            ),
        )
    );

JsonObject data = JsonParser.parse(reader)  // le o reader convertendo para  json
        getAsJsonObject();                  // retorna como JsonObject

// ...
```

Você também poderia mudar a informação de tamanho da mensagem de int para long.

Comment: Então, o problema é que a variável tamanhoMsg não está vindo certa, pois no cliente eu faço o seguinte para pegar o tamanho: "msg.length". Lenght é int, e como a String é grande, está estourando o tamanho máximo de inteiro, e assim, não está vindo o tamanho correto.

Comment: Então tenta mudar a delimitação de uma mensagem pelo próprio protocolo JSON.